# How to transfer image upload from form to backend upload?

Tags: javascript

I managed to upload an image in form, but i want to save it to backend and then when i call it again using frontend i will b able to save a picture
[image: This is the form]

function code :

```
    addFilm: (title, description, release_year, language_id, rental_duration, rental_rate, length, replacement_cost, rating, special_features, category_id, actors, store_id, callback) => { //1.(1 ~ 3 are places to change code )
        var conn = db.getConnection(); // GET CONNECTION TO DB
        conn.connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return callback(err, null);
            } else {
                console.log('Connected Successfully!');
                var SQLstatement = //use backtick to go onto next line
                // first insert into film table
                    `insert into film (title,description,release_year,language_id,rental_duration,rental_rate,length,replacement_cost,rating,special_features)
                Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`; // 2.
                conn.query(SQLstatement, [title, description, release_year, language_id, rental_duration, rental_rate, length, replacement_cost, rating, special_features], (error, result_id) => { //3.
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        return callback(error, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        // second insert into film_category table
                        var SQLstatement = `insert into film_category (film_id,category_id) Values (?,?)`
                        conn.query(SQLstatement, [result_id.insertId, category_id], (error, result) => {
                            if (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                                return callback(error, null);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log(result);
                                // neeed check actor
                                console.log(actors);
                                var SQLstatement = ''
                                values = []
                                // add a new actor id with the same film id to the film_actor table
                                for (var k = 0; k < actors.length; k++) {
                                    if (k == actors.length - 1) {
                                        SQLstatement += `(?,?)`
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        SQLstatement += `(?,?),`
                                    }
    
                                    //  console.log(actors[k])
                                    values.push(actors[k])
                                    values.push(result_id.insertId)
                                }
                                var finalSQLstatement = `insert into film_actor (actor_id,film_id) Values ` + SQLstatement
                                conn.query(finalSQLstatement, values, (error, result) => {
                                    if (error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                        return callback(error, null);
                                    }
                                })
    
    
                                console.log(result_id.insertId);
                                var SQLstatement = //use backtick to go onto next line
                                // last insert into inventory with same film_id and store_id
                                    `insert into inventory(film_id,store_id) Values(?,?)`; // 2.
                                conn.query(SQLstatement, [result_id.insertId, store_id], (error, result) => { //3.
                                    conn.end();
                                    if (error) {
                                        console.log(error);
                                        return callback(error, null);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        console.log(result);
                                        return callback(null, result.insertId);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        })
    
                        // });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    
    },


app.get():
app.get('/view/:filmid',function(req, res){
    var filmid = req.params.filmid;

    actorDB.getDetails(filmid, function(err, result){
        if(!err){
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result);
        }else{
            res.status(500).send("Some error");
        }
    });
}); 

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Customer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="nav">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/users/">All Users</a>
        </nav>

        <h1>Register a new DVD</h1>
        <form id="register-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="file-upload w-100">
                    <form class="image-upload-wrap d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                        style="height: 240px">
                        <input class="file-upload-input" type="file" onchange="readImage(this);" accept="image/*"
                            id="imageFile" />

                        <div class="drag-text w-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div id="imageErr" class="text-danger d-none">
                                Invalid Image
                            </div>
                            <h3>Drag photo here</h3>
                            <p>— or —</p>
                            <button class="btn bg-secondary text-white font-weight-bold text-center" type="button"
                                style="white-space: nowrap; z-index: 1055" id="addImage"
                                onclick="$('.file-upload-input').trigger( 'click' )">
                                Choose photo to upload
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="file-upload-content">
                        <img class="file-upload-image" style="border: 1px black solid" src="#" alt="your image"
                            id="imgPreview" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="release">Release:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="release" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lang">Language_id:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lang" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="rental_duration">Rental Duration:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rental_duration" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="rental_rate">Rental rate:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rental_rate" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="length">Length:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="replacement_cost">Replacement Cost:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="replacement_cost" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rating" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="special_features">Special Features:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="special_features" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category_id">Category ID:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_id" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="actors">Actors:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="actors" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="store_id">Store_id:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="store_id" required>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary ml-5">Reset</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-5" id="Logout">Log Out</button>
            <!-- <input type="reset" value="Reset">   -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8081";
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        const loggedInUserID = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("loggedInUserID"));
        console.log(token, loggedInUserID)

        function readImage(fileInput) {
            if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
                var imgReader = new FileReader();
                imgReader.onload = function (event) {
                    var wrap = document.querySelector(".image-upload-wrap");
                    if (wrap) {
                        wrap.classList.add("d-none");
                        wrap.classList.remove("d-flex");
                    }
                    var imgData = event.target.result.split(',')[1]; 
                    var postData = { image: imgData };
                    fetch('/upload-image.php', {
                      method: 'POST',
                      body: JSON.stringify(postData),
                      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                      console.log('Success:', data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                      console.error('Error:', error);
                    });

                    document.getElementById("addImage").style.display = "none";
                    var imgPreview = document.getElementById("imgPreview");
                    imgPreview.src = event.target.result;

                    var content = document.querySelector(".file-upload-content");
                    content.classList.add("d-flex", "justify-content-center", "align-items-center");
                    content.classList.remove("d-none");
                    
                    var btnSave = document.getElementById("save");
                    if (btnSave.classList.contains("btn-danger")) {
                        btnSave.classList.toggle("btn-danger");
                        btnSave.classList.add("btn-primary");
                        btnSave.innerHTML = "Save as promo picture";

                    }
                };
                imgReader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
            } else {
                removeUpload();
            }
        }


        if (token === null || isNaN(loggedInUserID)) {
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:3001/home";
        } else {
            $("#register-form").submit((event) => {
                // prevent page reload
                event.preventDefault();

                const title = $("#title").val();
                const description = $("#description").val();
                const release = $("#release").val();
                const lang = $("#lang").val();
                const rental_duration = $("#rental_duration").val();
                const rental_rate = $("#rental_rate").val();
                const length = $("#length").val();
                const replacement_cost = $("#replacement_cost").val();
                const rating = $("#rating").val();
                const feature = $("#special_features").val();
                const category_id = $("#category_id").val();
                const actors = $("#actors").val();
                const store_id = $("#store_id").val();

                const requestBody = {
                    title: title,
                    description: description,
                    release_year: release,
                    language_id: lang,
                    rental_duration: rental_duration,
                    rental_rate: rental_rate,
                    length: length,
                    replacement_cost: replacement_cost,
                    rating: rating,
                    special_features: feature,
                    category_id: category_id,
                    actors: actors,
                    store_id: store_id
                };
                let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
                console.log(requestBody);
                axios.post(`${baseUrl}/film`, requestBody, { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + token } })
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(requestBody)
                        window.location.href = "http://localhost:3001/home";
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        if (error.response.status === 400) {
                            alert("Validation failed");
                        } else {
                            alert("Something unexpected went wrong.");
                        }
                    });
            });
            $("#Logout").click(function () {
                window.localStorage.clear();
                localStorage.removeItem("token");
                localStorage.removeItem("loggedInUserID");
                window.location.assign("http://localhost:3001/login");
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need help in parsing the data, even now as i try to submit the form it says Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
at imgReader.onload.

Comment: To upload a file to your server, your form should be something like `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: to send any file to backend via api you need to set header `content-type="multipart/form-data"`